# Unknown column error when using two COUNT statements in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run 2 different occurrences of COUNT in one SQL query but am getting this error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'po.product_id' in 'on clause'

Here is the sql:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) vouchersleft, `prod_name`,
        `start_date`, 
        `end_date`,
        `reg_price`,
        `sale_price`,
        bbp.`prod_id`,
        `vouch_limits`,
        `sp_name`,
        `order_id`,
        `img_name`,
        `outlets`
        FROM `vouchers` as `v`
        INNER JOIN `bb_products` as `bbp` ON bbp.`prod_id` = v.`product_id`
        INNER JOIN `service_providers` as `sp` ON sp.`service_provider_id` = bbp.`provider_id`
        INNER JOIN `prod_pics` as `pp` ON pp.`prod_id` = bbp.`prod_id`
        INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `outlet_id`) AS `outlets` FROM `prod_outlets` GROUP BY `product_id`) as `po` ON po.`product_id` = bbp.`prod_id`
        WHERE `frontend` = :frontend
        AND bbp.`featured` = :featured
        AND `order_id` = :order_id
        AND pp.`featured` = :featured_img
        GROUP BY bbp.`prod_id`
```

Comment: You typically GROUP BY all the columns you select, except those who arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join by the column it has to be returned by your `SELECT` statement. Include `product_id` in column list that you're selecting.

Change:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `outlet_id`) AS `outlets` FROM `prod_outlets` GROUP BY `product_id`) as `po` ON po.`product_id` = bbp.`prod_id`
```

To:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT `product_id`, COUNT(DISTINCT `outlet_id`) AS `outlets` FROM `prod_outlets` GROUP BY `product_id`) as `po` ON po.`product_id` = bbp.`prod_id`
```

Without the column selected, `product_id` is not visible outside of this intermediate table (here named `po`). This is why you get an error **unknown column**, because only known column is `outlets`.

Answer (score 1):

Including the column in the `GROUP BY` is not enough.  You need to also include it in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(DISTINCT `outlet_id`) AS `outlets`
FROM `prod_outlets`
GROUP BY `product_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just join directly

```
SELECT COUNT(*) vouchersleft, `prod_name`,
        `start_date`, 
        `end_date`,
        `reg_price`,
        `sale_price`,
        bbp.`prod_id`,
        `vouch_limits`,
        `sp_name`,
        `order_id`,
        `img_name`,
         COUNT(DISTINCT po.`outlet_id`) AS `outlets`
        FROM `vouchers` as `v`
        INNER JOIN `bb_products` as `bbp` ON bbp.`prod_id` = v.`product_id`
        INNER JOIN `service_providers` as `sp` ON sp.`service_provider_id` = bbp.`provider_id`
        INNER JOIN `prod_pics` as `pp` ON pp.`prod_id` = bbp.`prod_id`
        RIGHT JOIN `prod_outlets`  as `po` ON po.`product_id` = bbp.`prod_id`
        WHERE `frontend` = :frontend
        AND bbp.`featured` = :featured
        AND `order_id` = :order_id
        AND pp.`featured` = :featured_img
        GROUP BY bbp.`prod_id`
```